# React-flatpickr: Setting minDate to current day and time causes blank field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, flatpickr

I have a react-flatpickr calendar with time enabled, trying to set minDate to the current date and time using the moment library causes the input to go blank when the time is reached.

Input field before time is reached

[image: Input field before time is reached]

Input field after time is reached

[image: Input field after time is reached]

note that the graying out is done by me and not part of the issue

[image: Here is what my relevant code looks like]

I have tried seperating the current day and time into both minDay and minTime however minTime affects every single day and I only need it for the current day

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this in the future the way I fixed it is by setting minDate to 'today' and not setting minTime initally and adding logic in the onChange to check if it is changing to the current day and if so to set the minTime to the current time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my onChange the following way Here is the function for setDate name is the name of flatpicker and date is the selected value from flatPicker  .

```
if (name == 'startDate' && new Date() > date) {
  setDirectListingDate({ ...directListingDate, startDate: new Date() });
} else { 
 setDirectListingDate({ ...directListingDate, [name]: date });
 }
```